# EE service design and OO modelling

Tags: java, spring, oop

Increasingly in our spring (or equivalent) wired world of services, the Java code I see seems more & more procedural, with not much emphasis on modelling the problem in OO.

For example, a service that has stuff to do may well inline that in the service method in the singleton service class – maybe over several hundred lines. Alternatively, local methods may be created, but because the service is stateless, these are invariably called with a stack (no pun intended) of needed args. It’s  noisy.

Guess this maybe my original OO background in Smalltalk to the fore here, but modelling the problem in OO has always seemed to me to be the way to go. That is,  modelling with objects which have state as well as behaviour.

An alternative approach might be to create a stateful prototype delegate invoked from the service, which is either wired or loaded with the necessary (entities, singleton DAO/services etc) In addition some other decorators might be created to wrap entities (esp collections) to provide some model list behaviour (I have a list af accounts, I have some list based behaviour  – this must be a class holding the list, it must not be just the technical List class and its usage behaviour inlined in the service (but usually is))

But.

Creating some objects of this kind uses memory, and in a high throughput environment, this might result in the creation of thousands of small strategy/decorator instances.
So what is the real world impact of that? Will the extra GC screw the performance or, assuming a JVM instance around a couple of GB, can Java cope?
Has anyone delivered a Java SOA based on these principles? Are there any papers on the subject?

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: I read Uncle Bob and learned that output parameters were almost equivalent to side effects and by nature quite ugly. Now I constantly have to use them in stateless beans. I try my best to delegate logic to local object instances, but at the end of the day there's a limit as to how "text book" I can go with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Real-world problems usually *are* a mix of object-based and procedural logic, especially in the business world where transactions involve needing to manipulate a number of distinct objects simultaneously. Certainly most real code could use improvement and refactoring, especially after a few years of moving-target requirements, and better understanding and use of AspectJ could clean up a lot of the procedural boilerplate, but it doesn't make sense to force all logic into a strong OOP pattern if it doesn't match the way that a real-world instructor would describe it to a trainee.

What you're describing is basically the Command pattern, and while there are situations where it is useful (it's essentially the role of `Runnable`), it's usually not worth using unless there are time-based considerations (serial execution, parallelism) or the transaction itself needs to be persistent (such as for banking).

Comment: But I meant business model behaviour hardly something that should sit under AOP - unless you wanted to hide it. Use AOP for anti corruption code but not for core behaviour.

The delegate in this case is a stateful command, tho within the current thread of course. IMHO this is always worth doing if it simplifies the code. Unless (my actual question) this compromises performance unacceptably.

As an aside I'm continually puzzled by the assertion boiler plate _must_ be removed (like it causes brain damage or something) BP is invariably simple...

Comment: @StripLight It may be simple, but it's redundant, and it's usually copied in many different places. If it can be abstracted out to advice, it makes the code more readable and more maintainable. Spring's `@Transactional` is an excellent example of this; there's no need to scatter transaction handling all over your code, with the increased risk of bugs from typos or failure to update, when you can write it in one place and apply it wherever needed.